# Django nested threaded comments - no text area

Tags: python, django, comments

I'm following this tutorial to get nested comments in my django web app:

http://www.maxburstein.com/blog/django-threaded-comments/

```
<!-- comments  -->
            <h1>Opinion</h1>
                <form id="postcomment" method="post" action="">
                    {{form.as_p}}
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
                <ul id="commenters">
                {% for c in comment_tree %}     
                    <li id="{{c.id}}" class="c" style="margin-left:{{c.depth|add:c.depth}}em;">
                        <p class="poster">Anonymous - {{c.date_create|naturaltime}}</p>
                        <p>{{c.content}}</p>
                        <p><a href="" class="reply">reply</a></p>
                    </li>
                {% empty %}
                    <li>There are currently no comments. You can be first</li> 
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            <!-- end comments -->
```

The problem is that I see only 'Submit' button, and information "There are currently no comments. You can be first!" - there is no text area where I can put my comment.

I think my problem could be connected with {{form.as_p}}, but I've checked all my code and can't find an answer.

SOLVED

I've found my problem. It was in views.py.
I do not pass the form variable in return

def address_detail(request, id_address):

```
adres = get_object_or_404(mod_address, id = id_address)

form = mod_address_comment_form(request.POST or None)


data = mod_address.objects.select_related().all().annotate(
            longitude=F('mod_address_localisation__longitude'),
            latitude=F('mod_address_localisation__latitude')
        )                                  



data = list(data.values('id','mod_address_category','mod_address_comment', 
        'mod_address_localisation', 
        'longitude',
        'latitude',
))

comment_tree = mod_address_comment.objects.all().order_by('path')

data = json.dumps(data)  
data = json.loads(data)
return render(request, 'serwis/address_detail.html', {'address_detail_object': adres, 'comment_tree': comment_tree})
```

When I changed last line to:

```
return render(request, 'serwis/address_detail.html', {'address_detail_object': adres, 'comment_tree': comment_tree, 'form':form})
```

I can see text area.

I leave this comment for another users :)

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Of course, but which part of the code? HTML, models.py? My code isn't on git or somewhere..